# How can I fix exited with code 1 in docker build?

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I need help with docker-compose. I build react-app but with container exited with code 1. I dont know what is wrong, I am newbie in docker.

I am trying to display rest api from my app.js in api folder into my react-app. It builds api folder fine but my react folder gets with exited with code 1.

I am using win11 and WSL with ubuntu20.04

EDIT. I put here also my App.js from react app. Should not be added app.listen somewhere or something ?

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {

   const [pilots, setPilots] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
     fetch('http://localhost:4000/')
     .then( res => res.json())
     .then( data => setPilots(data))
   }, [])

   return (
     <div> 
       <h1> F1 Pilots</h1>
       {pilots && pilots.map(pilot => (
       <div key={pilot.id}>{pilot.name}</div> 
       ))}
     </div>
   );

}

export default App;
```

Here is my Dockerfile for react app

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "start"]
```

And here is my docker-compose file. React app starts with my-app:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
 api:
    build: ./api
    container_name: zadanie1-c1
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
      - ./api:/node_modules  

 my-app:
    build: ./my-app
    container_name: zadanie1-c2
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

My container for react app is always in exited mode.

edit. Added logs from container

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936

 throw err;

 ^


 Error: Cannot find module '/app/start'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)

at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)

at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)

at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

requireStack: []

}


Node.js v17.7.2
```

Comment: There'll be an actual error in the logs. Please find that and add it to your question.

Comment: The `volumes:` block overwrites everything the image does; it shouldn't be necessary to run the image, and I think you have a mistake in that block.  Does deleting the `volumes:` help things?  (`container_name:` is also unnecessary, though it shouldn't be harmful.)

Comment: No it does not help at all.

Comment: And what about ports? are they okay? because in that docker files is imo nothing wrong.